# rust how to find servcie name and port. with winsock

Tags: rust, winsock

I have one question.

I was using this.
SERVENT structure (winsock.h)

But, I can't find anything similar.
Let me know how to find service name and port number.

Comment: This question needs to be expanded to be answerable. Please review [Stackoverflow Guidelines](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwij3YDF2Yz7AhVREsAKHc7MBAQQFnoECB0QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fhelp%2Fhow-to-ask&usg=AOvVaw00xttYhbqoB7L7CXC05R8r)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is somewhat lacking but this might be of interest:

https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Networking/WinSock/fn.getservbyname.html

https://microsoft.github.io/windows-docs-rs/doc/windows/Win32/Networking/WinSock/fn.getservbyport.html

https://github.com/microsoft/windows-rs

https://crates.io/crates/windows

**TL;DR:**
`cargo add windows` and add `Win32_Networking_WinSock` as a feature to cargo.toml